# Как подружить ffmpeg и visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ffmpeg

Как подружить ffmpeg и visual studio. Можно скачать где-то lib и dll для студии?

Comment: Что значит "подружить" и что хотите сделать?

Comment: подключить данную библиотеку к проекту в visual studio

Comment: Собственно, проект то какой? Добавьте метку к вопросу (c#, c++ ...).

Comment: проект Qt c++. хочу сделать видеоредактор

Comment: А это не работает: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC ?

Comment: так много ошибок

Comment: а где скачать ffmpeg? https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ Какие файлы именно нужно качать?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows) или [здесь](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT) есть подробные инструкции.
Если ты хочешь подключать нужные тебе заголовочные файлы и библиотеки, то надо качать с [этой](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) страницы версию DEV. Затем, когда соберешь библиотеки по инструкции, тебе надо будет их подключить к проекту, в котором они будут использоваться в настройках проекта. Если с этим будут проблемы - напиши комментарий к вопросу. Дам и к этому инструкцию.